# Mark unsorted recents photos in iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, photos, sort, album

I've a habit of sorting all my 'recent' photos into different local albums on my iPhone. I've 30,000+ photos in 'recent' album and NOT all are sorted in various local albums.
How can I mark the photos in 'recent' albums, all the photos which are NOT sorted/present in any other existing local album?
After marking those unsorted photos from 'recent' album, I will easily sort it out to various local albums and stay organised.
Secondly, I'd like all my iPhone photos albums to be synced with macOS Photos app albums without duplication. How is that possible without using third-party tools?

Comment: Do you sync iPhone photos to Photos on Mac? If yes, make a smart album with the condition <album> <is not> <any> to find all the photos that aren't in any album. To limit the search to recent photos, add another condition for photos taken or added in the last X days.

Comment: Yes, I can sync iPhone photos with macOS Photos app. However, I can only sync the photos from "recent" album from iPhone photos to macOS Photos app. The smart albums can only be made in macOS Photos app. If I can't sync photos from other iPhone photo albums to macOS Photos app albums then I can't make use of smart albums of macOS Photos app to figure out all the "recent" iPhone photos NOT sorted in any album.